# what is the plus (+) in hdfs after the list of rights on a file or folder?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I execute

```
hdfs dfs -ls /projects
```

I get for example a list of folders like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x+  - user1 group1          0 2020-05-06 09:54 /projects/project1
drwxrwxr-x   - user2 group2          0 2020-05-28 09:49 /projects/project2
drwxrwxr-x+  - user3 group3          0 2020-03-12 14:20 /projects/project3
```

What does the plus in **drwxrwxr-x+** mean? The folder /projects/project2 doesn't have ACLs.
Does the plus mean that a folder/file has ACLs defined on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed it right. Any file or directory that has an ACL to it will have a `+` character appended to the permission string.

Ref: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Shell_Commands